# Generate own link instead of pagination render default link - laravel 5.0

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pagination, laravel-5

Developed one new laravel 5.0 app. There I have used ajax concept for every pages. Each and every request and response will travel through ajax.

Main Page:

```
  <nav><li onclick="view('bydproject')"><a>View ByDProject Data </a></li>   </nav>
  <div id='main'></div>
```

Ajax call :

```
function view(url)
  {
      fullurl = "http://localhost:8000/" + url ;
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
      {
        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", fullurl, true);
    xhttp.send();
   }
```

In one of the case, I have used pagination concept for some page.

Conctroller:

```
$employees = ByDEmployee::where('first_name' , 'LIKE', '%'.$Data.'%')->paginate(20);
return view('bydemployee.view_all_employees', compact('employees'));
```

view_all_employees.blade.php

```
@foreach($employees as $employee)
    {{ $employee->first_name }}
    //Display 
@endforeach

{{ $employees->render() }}
```

In this situation pagination render link generate that own link. instead of that link I have to generate my ajax call? whether it is possible ?

Ex: Instaed of this

```
<li><a href="http://localhost:8000/bydemployee?page=2" rel="prev">&laquo;</a></li>
```

Link looks like this

```
<li><a onclick=view('bydemployee?page=2') rel="prev">&laquo;</a></li>
```

Comment: I need to generate link like this . <li><a onclick=view('bydemployee?page=2') rel="prev">&laquo;</a></li>.  Pagination Render link.

Comment: If I click render link its move on to the separate page. (http://localhost:8000/bydemployee?page=2). Instead of this, wanna travel through ajax.

Comment: ya in view, i have used foreach.

Comment: I'm not generating my own link. I just copied this line from view source page from browser(<li><a href="http://localhost:8000/bydemployee?page=2" rel="prev">&laquo;</a></li> ). this line is automatically generated by {{ $employees->render() }} this line.

Comment: so that i need to generate my own line instead of generating default link by pagination render

Comment: those li ul elements are automatically generated. also generate default link. I need to change that link to custom format. how to do that ?

Comment: For that, you will have to share generated `ul - li` elements..

Comment: <td colspan="6">
         <ul class="pagination"><li class="disabled"><span>«</span></li> <li class="active"><span>1</span></li><li><a href="http://localhost:8000/bydemployee?page=2">2</a></li></ul>
       </td>

Comment: What should happen for __«__ ?

Comment: thats indicate previous page

Comment: How you expect URL to be for that element ?